Typescript breaking change with pushing and assigning a 'derived' value into a 'base' array
I haven't been able to locate the specific breaking change.
Q: may anyone explain the reason why this behaviour shown now gives a 'Object literal may only specific known properties' error since TS 5+?
Playground: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=5.0.4#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4oN4FgBQyywAJgFzIgCuAtgEbQDcBAvgQaJLIigCLTAAbhBLIIAD0ggSGNJhwEiIODQgUMYKKADmzfG3wEEAexAbikGhgrosAbQC6yALzJHeggBsIYCxBoAjBT8WsIket6+wJYATMECYR740f4BLsjYxOTIAQA0lCpqyADkYAAWwLKVyMYA1shQENpwUCTeGBjFyCx6KVYAdAAOVBhlABR9AQCUSX0YQyPjE7HpmaQUMfnKqhSlFVWyAHIA8gAqNfWgyACs-QAM-QAs+XRUUbJ1xCDIj-0AnP1rl0WFMZkA
Code:
interface Base {
  id: number;
}

interface Derived extends Base {
  name: string;
}

const items: Base[] = [];

let item1: Derived;
let item2: Derived;

item1 = { id: 1, name: 'this is ok regardless' };
items.push(item1);

items.push((item2 = { id: 2, name: 'this is NOT ok in 5.0.4, but is ok in 4.9.5' }));


It might be a change in the order that types are checked e.g. if you say "Add { id: 2, name: 'name' } to items and also assign it to items2" then it would not work because the literal is not compatible with Base but if you say "Assign { id: 2, name: 'name' } to items2 and push items2 to items" then it will work because items2 extends Base. Generally inline assignments are not great so I would personally avoid them

yes it does seem like its consciously checking types in a different order. I think inline assignments can harm readability but also, they're a language feature, so I guess I'd like to discover if there is a particular rationale why they prefer it this way or if it is just something that accidentally got broken and there is a fault with how the compiler infers the type here

The behaviour seems incorrect, and I could not find any statement about the change. It appears to appear in TS 5.0, but I don't see it in the TS 5.0 changelog. I would suggest a ticket on the TypeScript github would be a better place to get answers

pardon my potential dumbass but the variable assignment is inside the push method?
current = items.push((item2 = { id: 2, name: 'this is NOT ok in 5.0.4, but is ok in 4.9.5' })); : expected = items.push({ id: 2, name: 'this is NOT ok in 5.0.4, but is ok in 4.9.5' }); I apperciate it'll return the right thing but that'll trip up TSC for sure

This change occurred between 4.9.5 and 5.0.2 and it is specifically related to how contextual types are cached. [github.com] [1]

Background
Assignments return the value of their right hand side. The assignment x = y returns y.
In the case below: [2]
item = { id: 2, name: 'this is NOT ok in 5.0.4, but is ok in 4.9.5' }
The return value of the assignment is the object literal:
{ id: 2, name: 'this is NOT ok in 5.0.4, but is ok in 4.9.5' }
During this assignment, the object literal is contextually inferred to be of type Derived.
Pre 4.9.5 and 4.9.5, this contextual type is cached but post 4.9.5, it no longer is.

What this means is that pre 4.9.5, after the assignment, the type of the object literal returned from the assignment is Derived. This type is cached and is assignable to Base but post 4.9.5, the caching is not done so the type of the object literal is rechecked to use in the assignment to the parameter of type Base. After rechecking, excess property check throws an error.

A simple fix would be type asserting the object literal before assignment or type asserting the result of the assignment (i.e. type asserting the object literal after assignment):
item = { id: 2, name: 'this is NOT ok in 5.0.4, but is ok in 4.9.5' } as Derived
OR
(item = { id: 2, name: 'this is NOT ok in 5.0.4, but is ok in 4.9.5' }) as Derived
This will prevent any form of contextual type inference on the object literal.

[1] In my humble opinion, it isn’t a major breaking change, that is probably why it wasn’t documented.
[2] The case uses a contrived example which is emulated from the example in the OP but not exact. This is for brevity.

I would argue that this is a good change and it provides stricter checks for literals.

This makes sense. I did a low-level debug of the two compilers with OP's code and got the difference being in code modified by this, (commit), described as "The assignment expression x = y has the same type as y with any object literal freshness preserved. Previously, object literal freshness was stripped." Freshness results in isPerformingExcessPropertyChecks being true in checker.ts... That's certainly in the same line to what you describe

This behavior is intentional, here is another example:
interface Pet {
  name: string;
}
let pet: Pet;
const dog = { name: "Lassie", owner: "Rudd Weatherwax" };
pet = dog; //works
// error out  
pet =  { name: "Lassie", owner: "Rudd Weatherwax" };

In the first case, we assign the dog object to the pet variable. This is allowed because even though dog has an extra property, it still fulfills the Pet interface requirement. (TypeScript is structure typing)
The second case is directly assigning an object literal to the pet variable: { name: "Lassie", owner: "Rudd Weatherwax" }. TypeScript enforces type safety to disallow the extra property in this case. This is to prevent human mistakes in passing a literal object directly.
If we cast or assert the internal object (we are telling the ts compiler that we know what we are doing), then it will allow it.
for example, this will work
pet =  { name: "Lassie", owner: "Rudd Weatherwax" } as Pet

